# How to annotate errors using Swashbuckle Swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I've used the Swashbuckle swagger Nuget package in a .net framework webapi.

I'm trying to annotate api responses.  It's great for success responses, I just specify the type of my object model:

```
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(WebAPI.Models.APIResponse), Description = "Successful operation.")]
```

If I return an error like this:

```
return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Document not found.");
```

I get the following json / xml responses

```
{
  "Message": "Document not found."
}

<Error>
    <Message>Document not found.</Message>
</Error>
```

If there is an unhandled exception, I will get an http 500 with a json / xml response like this (Not, the exception details are only returned when executing the rest call from the local machine.:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "This is a test error",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
  "StackTrace": "   at WebAPI.Controllers.MyController.Post(Guid id) in ..."
}

<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>This is a test error</ExceptionMessage
    <ExceptionType>System.Exception</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>   at WebAPI.Controllers.MyController.Post(Guid id) in ...</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

For these responses, how do I annotate them with Swashbuckle?

I've tried:

```
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(HttpResponseMessage), Description = "Error.")]

[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(HttpResponseException), Description = "Error.")]

[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(Exception), Description = "Error.")]
```

In the model example section I either get the message "Object is not a primitive" as in the case of Exception and HttpResponse, or the example does not reflect what the response would actually look like.  For example HttpResponseException looks like this in the swagger ui:

```
{
  "Response": {},
  "Message": "string",
  "Data": {},
  "InnerException": {},
  "StackTrace": "string",
  "HelpLink": "string",
  "Source": "string",
  "HResult": 0
}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HttpResponseException>
  <!-- invalid XML -->
  <Message>string</Message>
  <Data>
    <!-- additional elements allowed -->
  </Data>
  <!-- invalid XML -->
  <StackTrace>string</StackTrace>
  <HelpLink>string</HelpLink>
  <Source>string</Source>
  <HResult>1</HResult>
</HttpResponseException>
```

Comment: Yes `SwaggerResponse` is the proper way, If you set the right type in the UI it should look like this: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=IHttpActionResult#/IHttpActionResult/IHttpActionResult_GetById

Comment: Here is the code for that link:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/IHttpActionResultController.cs#L21